# grep + match exactly IP address with Regular Expression

Tags: linux, perl, grep, solaris, ksh

my target is to match exactly IP address with three octes , while the four IP octet must be valid octet -  between <0 to 255>

For example I have the following IP's in file

```
$ more file    
192.9.200.10
192.9.200.100
192.9.200.1555
192.9.200.1
192.9.200.aaa
192.9.200.@
192.9.200.:
192.9.200
192.9.200.
```

I need to match the first three octets - 192.9.200  while four octet must be valid ( 0-255)

so finally - expects result should be:

```
192.9.200.10
192.9.200.100
192.9.200.1
```

the basic syntax should be as the following:

```
IP_ADDRESS_THREE_OCTETS=192.9.200
cat file | grep -x $IP_ADDRESS_THREE_OCTETS.[  grep‏ Regular Expression syntax ]
```

Please advice how to write the right "grep regular Expression" in the four octets  in order to match the three octets , while the four octets must be valid?

Comment: `cat file |` is a waste. Use `<file` instead, or pass `file` as an argument to `grep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use some high-level tools to convert the text to a regex pattern, so you might as well use just that.

```
perl -ne'
    BEGIN { $base = shift(@ARGV); }
    print if /^\Q$base\E\.([0-9]+)$/ && 0 <= $1 && $1 <= 255;
' "$IP_ADDRESS_THREE_OCTETS" file
```

If hardcoding the base is acceptable, that reduces to:

```
perl -ne'print if /^192\.9\.200\.([0-9]+)$/ && 0 <= $1 && $1 <= 255' file
```

Both of these snippets also accept input from STDIN.

---

For a full IP address:

```
perl -ne'
    BEGIN { $ip = shift(@ARGV); }
    print if /^\Q$ip\E$/;
' 1.2.3.4 file
```

or

```
perl -nle'
    BEGIN { $ip = shift(@ARGV); }
    print if $_ eq $ip;
' 1.2.3.4 file
```

Comment: hi I am very like your answer with perl line liner especially the “Q and E” that replace the backslash “\” 
but one more question can you give another example from your answer – how to match exactly IP address with four octets  , the solution of perl save the option to set “\” before the “.”

Comment: @Eytan, Added exact IP address solution to answer as requested.

Comment: @Eytan, By the way, I split the code across multiple lines for readability, but it also works if you put it all one one line.

Answer (score 2):

Regexp is not good for comparing numbers, I'd do this with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F. '$1==192 && $2==9 && $3==200 && $4>=0 && $4<=255 && NF==4' file
192.9.200.10
192.9.200.100
192.9.200.1
```

If you really want to use `grep` you need the `-E` flag for extended regexp or use `egrep` because you need alternation:

```
$ grep -Ex '192\.9\.200\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])' file
192.9.200.10
192.9.200.100
192.9.200.1

$ IP=192\.9\.200\.

$ grep -Ex "$IP(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])" file
```

Note: You must escaped `.` to mean a literal period.

Comment: `\|` provides alternation without `-E`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1]?[1-9][0-9]?).){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1]?[1-9]?[0-9])$'
```

This expression will not match IP addresses with leading 0s. e.g., it won't match 192.168.1.01

This expression will not match IP addresses with more than 4 octets. e.g., it won't match 192.168.1.2.3

Comment: What this have to do with the question?

Comment: That expression does not match a value between 100 and 109.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be certain that what you have is a valid IPv4 address, you can always check the return value of [`inet_aton()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html#%24ip_address-=-inet_aton-%24string) (part of the `Socket` core module).